# How can I check Confluent Platform log4j version?

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j, confluent-platform

I use **confluent-6.0.1** and I want to check log4j version.

How can I see the version of **log4j**?

Comment: what is your exact dependency name? they usually have a group and artifact ID.

Comment: it is Confluent Platform: 6.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I used the graddle dependency file of the project,

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka/blob/6.0.1-post/gradle/dependencies.gradle

normally   log4j: "1.2.17-cp2"

Comment: This is just the broker, not the rest of Confluent Platform

Answer (score 0):

That version what you have are not impacted by this issue
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html#CVE-2021-45046

Versions Affected: all versions from 2.0-beta9 through 2.12.1 and 2.13.0 through 2.15.0

Comment: There are multiple components of Confluent Platform. Some are affected https://support.confluent.io/hc/en-us/articles/4412615410580-December-2021-Log4j-Vulnerabilities-Advisory